# TFJS example of tf.layers.globalAveragePooling2d()

Tags: tensorflow.js

I am creating my first algorithm in TFJS Layers by translating this tutorial
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lWUGZarlbORaHYUZlF9muCgpPl8pEvve#scrollTo=nhYhP30NKlAp

Can I get an example of globalAveragePooling2d in TFJS? Thank you

```
this.model = tf.sequential();
this.model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
  inputShape: [224, 224 , 3],
  kernelSize: 3,
  activation: 'relu',
  filters: 8
}));
this.model.add(
  tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize: 3})
);
this.model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
  inputShape: [16, 16],
  kernelSize: 3,
  activation: 'relu',
  filters: 8
}));
this.model.add(
  tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize: 3})
);

// How to use this?
this.model.add(tf.layers.globalAveragePooling2d());

this.model.add(tf.layers.timeDistributed(
  {layer: tf.layers.dense({units: this.outputCount})}));
this.model.add(tf.layers.activation({activation: 'softmax'}));
this.model.compile({
  loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy',
  optimizer: 'sgd',
  metrics: ['accuracy']
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.layers.timeDistributed` cannot be used after `tf.layers.globalAveragePooling2d` for the first return a 2d layer whereas the latter expects at least a 3d layer. They can be combined only if the layer shape is reshaped before.

Currently an empty object needs to be passed to `tf.layers.globalAveragePooling2d`, for it tries to access `arg.name`. It will throw an error if arg is not an object

```js
let model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
  inputShape: [224, 224 , 3],
  kernelSize: 3,
  activation: 'relu',
  filters: 8
}));
model.add(
  tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize: 3})
);
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
  inputShape: [16, 16],
  kernelSize: 3,
  activation: 'relu',
  filters: 8
}));
model.add(
  tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize: 3})
);
// How to use this?
model.add(tf.layers.globalAveragePooling2d({}));

/*model.add(tf.layers.timeDistributed(
  {layer: tf.layers.dense({units: 3, activation: 'softmax'})}));*/
model.compile({
  loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy',
  optimizer: 'sgd',
  metrics: ['accuracy']
});

model.summary()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.7.2"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```